# Difference between these 3 shopping cart calls?

Tags: cart

I read these 3 snippets from the Internet of obtaining shopping cart contents.

Snippet 1

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$cartItems = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($cartItems as $item) {
    // get item details here
}
```

Snippet 2

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item) {
    // get item details here
}
```

Snippet 3

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$cartItems = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
foreach($cartItems as $item) {
    // get item details here
}
```

What are the difference the snippets above? All of them return the same items.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
$cartItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

Will return all visible items in the cart. For more info on visible / not visible items look [here](https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/magento-what-is-the-difference-between-getallvisibleitems-and-getallitems/). (In short, this kind of function would return a configurable but not its simple)

2.

`$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems();`

```
Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
public function getItems()
{
    if (!$this->getQuote()->getId()) {
        return array();
    }
    return $this->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
}
```

Under the hood it is getting the quote and getting the items collection, so will not be doing visible filtering as scenario 1. (In short, this kind of function would return a configurable AS WELL AS its simple)

3.

`$cartItems = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItems()`

```
Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart
/**
 * Retrieve cart instance
 *
 * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
 */
public function getCart()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
}
```

Under the hood this calls `getSingleton('checkout/cart')`, from there it's the same as scenario 2.

So the main difference is in 1, where it filters for [visible items](https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/magento-what-is-the-difference-between-getallvisibleitems-and-getallitems/).

Comment: How would you add the same visibility check to method 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet 1**

`$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();` give Current cart Object.It provide.

**Snippet 2**

```
$cartItems = Mage::getModel("checkout/cart")->getItems();
```

**Snippet 3**

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$cartItems = $cartHelper->getCart();
```

Here:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')=$cartHelper->getCart()
```

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')` give singleton object of  Class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart`.

and  `$cartItems->getItems()` give null value if current session  `did not have any cart items`.
please check  on this class

```
public function getItems()
    {
    //  !$this->getQuote() =Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
        if (!$this->getQuote()->getId()) { 
            return array();
        }
        return $this->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
    }
```

** **More details will provide soon**